# How to resolve typings in npm nested modules

Tags: npm

```
src/cli_inv.ts:29:16 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/home/martin/github/vlikin/node-typescript-website/server/node_modules/inversify/dts/container/container").Container' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/martin/github/vlikin/node-typescript-website/server/node_modules/inversify-commander-utils/node_modules/inversify/dts/container/container").Container'.
```

I receive a such error. I am developing a PROGMAM that uses packages INVERSIFY, INVERSIFY-COMMANDER. INVERSIFY-COMMANDER is a library created by me and it is depends on INVERSIFY module. The problem occurs during the program compilation. The object of INVERSIFY is created and passed to INVERSIFY-COMMANDER But the library requires the object of nested libraries. I see that there are two items of the same library.

Hello. I see that I do not understand how dependencies and nested libraries work. I suggested to get a flat structure but I received the nested structure. I read about. It looked easy. But...

Could anybody clarify the picture? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM is smart enough. In my case:

- Shared dependencies have be excluded from package.json of the library
  developed( INVERSIFY-COMMANDER).
- The shared libraries have to be
  defined on the top level PROGRAM.
- For a development case, the shared
  dependencies might be defined in the devDependency section.